# Delay before rendering issue using OpenGL save and render process is used

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, physics-engine

I have created a c++ compute program using GLFW OpenGL that calculates the simple physics of gravity on particles over a pre-defined time period, saving the calculated results to a standard GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. This is setup in a standard way:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vboSTATE);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboSTATE);
int bufferSize = (pCount * (4 * sizeof(GLfloat))) * (totalSteps);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

The data is saved using glCopyBufferSubData to get the data transferred between GPU buffers.

Once the simulation time has passed, the results (positions) are rendered with a simple draw call as follows, looping through the recorded data in steps:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, step, particleCount);
```

"step" being the physics step to render in the current frame. There is a pause before the rendering loop starts and this is linear in relation to the particle count. Using 1 particle, the delay seems to disappear, 100 and the delay is about 5 secs, 1000 particles and the delay is in the region of a minute or so and may even hang and crash the program.

The only thing I notice is that the buffer size is increasing with the number of particles in the simulation but it is not anything I would think of crazy - less than 1mb for 100 particles.

I had a previous program that would calculate and render in real-time within the same frame but the number of particles was limited (I am looking to get thousands at the end), but no delay was experienced. This has occured when I moved to this post-solving display style program.

Any ideas?? Thanks,

Comment: That sounds to me like your compute progam just takes that long.

Comment: Hi derhass - the compute physics solving part completes within a second for 100000 steps and 100 particles but the rendering of the historical data starts after a delay of 5 seconds. If the data is already present in the VBO and that was setup, initialised and accessed before the physics, why cause a delay in accessing afterwards??

Comment: I have no idea without seeing the code.

Comment: You state `"...physics solving part completes within a second for 100000 steps..."`.  Given the (possibly) asynchronous nature of all this how do you *know* it's completed?  What check do you perform?

Comment: @Nas25: "*The data is saved using glCopyBufferSubData to get the data transferred between GPU buffers.*" Why do you need to transfer it between buffers? Buffer objects in OpenGL are not typed; you can use the buffer you build the data in *directly* as the source for vertex rendering. Assuming you use the appropriate memory barriers of course.

Comment: @G.M. hmmmm, I was just considering this. The only validation I have of the results at the moment are the fact that they render correctly when finally loaded. Is there are more sure way of checking or validating this? I did run glFlush / glFinish after the solving stage but with no effective change...

Comment: @NicolBolas I am using an SSBO to do the fast compute physics and saving out the time series data one after the other to a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER so that I could render the results afterwards. Is there a better / more suitable way to do this?

Comment: You might want to look at [sync objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sync_Object).

Comment: @G.M. a sync object seems to be able to ensure OpenGL has finished commands but will this solve the issue of the delay? I can't see how this will...

Comment: @G.M. Would you approach this physics simulation and rendering process in the same way as I have? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Nas25: "*saving out the time series data one after the other to a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER*" `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is not a *type of buffer*; it is a *usage* of a buffer. There is no reason you cannot write to the buffer from a CS and then read from *the same buffer* via a vertex array. All buffers can be used for any buffer object usage, at any time. Copying is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by using the **glFinish()** after each copy operation to ensure the data was actually copied. I found the solution with the help of the suggestions provided by the community here. This does increase the loop times considerably but at least you know for sure openGL is finished writing and the data is ready to use...

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

In order to read data written by a CS, that data has to have been produced. And the more data there is that needs to be produced, the longer it will take. And therefore, the longer it will be between the writing and reading commands.

The buffer copy operation you lay out is pointless. OpenGL buffer objects do not have a type. It is 100% OK to use a buffer as an SSBO in one operation, then attach it to a VAO to use as source vertex array data for another operation.

Now, because writing to an SSBO uses [incoherent writing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Incoherent_Memory_Access), you will need an appropriate `glMemoryBarrier` between the write and the rendering operation that consumes the buffer. But you needed one of them between the write and the buffer copy anyway.

Comment: Hi Nicol, yes you're right I could have simply rendered from the same SSBO (as I did originally) but I actually don't need nor want to render every single time step of physics as it simply takes too long to watch at a time step of 1e-7. The CS only stores the previous time step / frame data and not the complete history of course... 

The idea is to save out a limited number of these steps in a longer history i.e. 1000 steps to a buffer over time. Then render the scene after the complete set of data has been stored in accessible memory (my current GL_ARRAY_BUFFER).... continued..

Comment: I understand this could have also been an SSBO or any other buffer type but the point is I need to be able to get the complete set of time history data and play back after the physics calculation phase..

I am using memory barriers where needed but the delay issue is occuring AFTER the physics calcs are completed and it's now time to render the scene from the saved data buffer...is there any alternative process of achieving this? I have read up on FBO textures, glreadpixels for movie files afterwards etc. but cannot see them being practical or efficient...

Comment: A small update - I entered the rendering loop stage and printed out this:
done........2.25703
done........2.26628
done........3.28073
done........26.3724

Comment: These are the seconds elapsed after entering the loop and printing at the end. The program executes the complete loop 3 times and hangs for over 20 seconds and starts to render the data. So I know the loop is entered but the GL rendering commands don't seem to execute... Nicol, I think you're right about a sync issue...but compute shaders, syncing etc is a new area for me...is there a good resource out there? Could you simply lay out how you would set such a program up in a generic sense? Thank you for your help so far..